# How to display a PDF from NSMutableData?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to display a PDF I have stored into an NSMutableData array.

My question is, how do I display a PDF to a view when I have the NSMutableData array.  I'd rather not save the file to disk if at all possible.  I'm not dealing with very large PDF's.  They would barely be 2 pages at most.

Ive seen a lot of info about displaying in a webview.  Is a requirement?  or just something people do?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is a "requirement". If you wish to, feel free to write your very own PDF rendering engine from scratch and include it in your app. It wouldn't be very practical, though.

Comment: Can you provide or point me to the direction of an example displaying a PDF in a webview with NSMutableData?

Comment: You can load the data in a web view or save it to a temporary file. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967600/how-to-display-nsdata-with-pdf-content-in-ios-uiwebview).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a particular requirement to use NSMutableData array then have a look at VFR reader it's a powerful PDF reader and nice and easy to implement.

You can either access a locally stored PDF or use one from a web site.

[VFR Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)