# How to open PDF in iOS not using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

How to open PDF file inside iOS app without UIWebView? I know but it is more easy to open it in UIWebView, but I have requirement.
I receive source of the PDF from SOAP service.

Any ideas?

I search Google but I did not found any clue.

**EDIT:** I prefer code to be in Objective-C if it is possible.

I found answer:
[How to display NSData with PDF content in iOS UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967600/how-to-display-nsdata-with-pdf-content-in-ios-uiwebview)

Sorry to make duplicate but I did not ask proper question.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787248/opening-a-file-by-uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, you can mark as duplicate for the link I gave. I can not myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 :**

```
        let theFileName = (self.my_object.my_pdf as NSString).lastPathComponent

        let url = URL(string:self.my_object.my_pdf)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            print(data)

            do {
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(theFileName)"
                let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
                try data.write(to: url)
                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: url)
                self.documentController.delegate = self
                self.documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)
                self.downloadBtn.action = #selector(self.downloadButtonTapped)
                //self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.downloadBtn, animated: true)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                self.downloadBtn.action = #selector(self.downloadButtonTapped)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

**Option 2:**

it works only and after **iOS 11.0+ && MacOS 10.4+**

```
import PDFKit
let pdfView = PDFView()


pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(pdfView)

pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.topAnchor).isActive = true

guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
    pdfView.document = document
}
```

Source : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

Comment: @Anbu.karthik make sure, you check minimum SDK support SDKs

iOS 11.0+
macOS 10.4+

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thanks.